# fs.readdirSync not work when I redirect with Router.push()

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I created a page that when the user clicks on a button it redirects him to the root page ('/'). But the root page has a code server-side that is not triggered when i redirect by the Router.push(), so it's throws a error because there's a code using node fs.

So, My question is: That's is a way of redirecting and executing this page server side?

**NOTE: The server-side code have to be executed (because it list the files inside server)**

The code is on github:

- https://github.com/vinicius-a-portela/dyn-wiki/blob/master/pages/wiki/index.js
- https://github.com/vinicius-a-portela/dyn-wiki/blob/master/components/TopWiki/index.js

TopWiki/, The redirect

```
  goTo = (item) => {
    console.log('goTo: ', item);
    Router.push(`/`);
  }
```

index.js, Root Page, this is the code that have to be executed server-side

```
const versions = articles.getVersions(`articles/${query.article}/`);
```

Articles.js (The FS that throws an error)

```
let articles = fs.readdirSync(folder);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SSR, only the first page that gets loaded on the client's browser is rendered on the server side. All the other pages are routed on the client side itself.

Forcing them to be executed on the server side would just increase the latency and server load. Instead what you can do is to make sure that code inside `getInitialProps` can be run both on server side and client side.

Since you already have a custom server configuration with ExpressJS up and running, I would suggest to move the Articles services as a route inside `server.js` and then call that API in `getInitialProps`.

Note: You can check for the presence of `req` and `res` arguments in `getInitialProps` to execute code that is **only** required on the server side.

Comment: Thx for the answer, was exactly that what I have done